# Using Select in Subsets

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
list = {{7, 6, 14, 14, 4}, {4, 9, 8, 11, 14}, {20, 12, 12, 11, 3}, {7,
4, 11, 7, 20}, {2, 13, 17, 11, 19}}
```

I did a test to identify where duplicates occur. So I created only subsets of `list [[1]]`:

```
sub = Subsets[list[[1]], {2}]
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 7 & 6 \\
 7 & 14 \\
 7 & 14 \\
 7 & 4 \\
 6 & 14 \\
 6 & 14 \\
 6 & 4 \\
 14 & 14 \\
 14 & 4 \\
 14 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

I tried to identify where the duplicates occur:

```
sub[[#1, 1]] == sub[[#1, 2]] & /@ Range[Length[sub]]
```

> {False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False}

I noticed that it exists, but why using Select is not selected ${14,14}$?

```
Select[list, sub[[#1, 1]] == sub[[#1, 2]] & /@ Range[Length[sub]]]
```

> $\{\}$

**EDIT**

I made some modifications based on the answers:

So I find out which lists there are duplicates:

```
Not[DuplicateFreeQ[list[[#]]]] & /@ Range[Length[list]]
```

> {True, False, True, True, False}

But still `Select` does not work the way I want it:

```
Select[list, Not[DuplicateFreeQ[list[[#]]]] & /@ Range[Length[list]]]
```

> $\{\}$

I want to get the lists that have duplicate parts, like this:

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  7 & 6 & 14 & 14 & 4 \\
>  20 & 12 & 12 & 11 & 3 \\
>  7 & 4 & 11 & 7 & 20 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: `Select[sub, Equal @@ # &]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete duplicate cases:

```
list = {{7, 6, 14, 14, 4}, {4, 9, 8, 11, 14}, {20, 12, 12, 11, 3}, {7,
    4, 11, 7, 20}, {2, 13, 17, 11, 19}}
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 7 & 6 & 14 & 14 & 4 \\
 4 & 9 & 8 & 11 & 14 \\
 20 & 12 & 12 & 11 & 3 \\
 7 & 4 & 11 & 7 & 20 \\
 2 & 13 & 17 & 11 & 19 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
Delete[list, 
 Position[Boole[DuplicateFreeQ[list[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[list]]], 
  1]]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  7 & 6 & 14 & 14 & 4 \\
>  20 & 12 & 12 & 11 & 3 \\
>  7 & 4 & 11 & 7 & 20 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 4):

In your case you can eliminate simply the duplicate by

```
DeleteDuplicates[list[[1]]]
```

but you perhaps this may be a part of a huge procedure and you do not know which numbers are duplicates. This is easy found with

```
Tally[list[[1]]]
```

which gives the order of multiplicity for each element.

EDIT

There is certainly a better way

```
list = {{7, 6, 14, 14, 4}, {4, 9, 8, 11, 14}, {20, 12, 12, 11, 3}, {7,
     4, 11, 7, 20}, {2, 13, 17, 11, 19}};
dup = Table[Tally[list[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}];
m = DeleteCases[
   Table[If[dup[[All, All, 2]][[i]] == {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 0, 
     list[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}], 0];
m // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Pick[list, DuplicateFreeQ /@ list, False]
 (* or *)
Select[list, DuplicateFreeQ@# == False &]
```

> {{7, 6, 14, 14, 4}, {20, 12, 12, 11, 3}, {7, 4, 11, 7, 20}}

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possibilities:

```
Pick[list, Replace[list, {{___, x_, ___, x_, ___} :> True, _ -> False}, {1}]]
Extract[list, Position[list, {___, x_, ___, x_, ___}]]
```

I found that the most elegant thing I could come up with was the pattern-matching approach, but it is bound to be slower if the sublists are long.